# Django template doesn't render a Variable's method

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am obviously victim of some dark magic...

Here is a template that I render :

```
context = Context({'my_cube': c})
template = Template(
    '{% load cube_templatetags %}'
    '{{ my_cube|inspect }} {{ my_cube.measure }}'
)
```

Here is the implementation of the `inspect` filter :

```
def inspect_object(obj):
    return obj.measure()
```

Here is what the rendering gives me :

```
>>> template.render(context)
u'6 None'
```

Does anyone know why the hell does the {{ my_cube.measure }} is not rendered properly, while obviously the function call is successful ???

NB : the measure function does no magic, no internal state is changed, I tested and it gives the same result each time, I also tested to put the inspect before the {{ cube.measure }}.... doesn't change anything. I have absolutely no clue on what's going on...

EDIT :
I know where it seems to be coming from. But it is still strange. For some reason, my object's attribute are not resolved by `template.Variable` :

```
>>> Variable('measure').resolve(c) == None
True
>>> Variable('testitesti').resolve(c) == None
True
>>> c.testitesti()
68
#implementation of testitesti :
def testitesti(self):
    return 68
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I found the damn thing !

The object I was trying to render had a `__getitem__` method that was just empty, so dictionnary indexing worked on this object (no error thrown), so of course the function call was not made !

Answer (score 0):

Inspect is being registered as a filter, yep? I'm assuming so else the whole template would choke. Is there a possible reserved word clash? `inspect` is a pretty loaded term, after all. Have you tried renaming that filter to something else?

Comment: Actually, this 'inspect' filter is just a debug filter that I wrote, after I observed the bug before... Plus, it would be a weird coincidence that there is a clash of names, but .... tadaaaa : I am still getting the expected value ! But I try ...